# how can i add multiple radio checked in one column

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I want multiple radio checkboxes. In one line it should be private or shared and in the second line, it should be with ATV or Without ATV so people on my web can select shared and with ATV or many variables. so basically two selections are needed and 4four checkboxes are divided into two groups.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .small-img-group {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .small-img-col {
      flex-basis: 24%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .counter1 {
      float: left;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    
    .counter2 {
      float: left;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .up,
    .down {
      display: inline-block;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 1px 1px;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 15px;
      line-height: 14px;
      height: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .up:hover,
    .down:hover {
      color: #fd0b3f;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .adults {
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
    .children {
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
    input {
      appearance: none;
      height: 21px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 42px;
      line-height: 24px;
      font-size: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    label[for=private] {
      position: relative;
      color: orangered;
      font-size: 20px;
      border: 2px solid orangered;
      border-radius: 5px;
      align-items: left;
      display: flex;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    label[for=shared] {
      position: relative;
      color: orangered;
      font-size: 20px;
      border: 2px solid orangered;
      border-radius: 5px;
      align-items: left;
      display: flex;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
      background-color: orangered;
      color: white;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      border: 10px solid white;
      background-color: orangered;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="container sproduct my-5 pt-5">
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100 pb-1" src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" alt="" id="MainImg" width="450">

        <div class="small-img-group">
          <div class="small-img-col">
            <img src="https://media.tacdn.com/media/attractions-splice-spp-674x446/09/99/99/87.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="small-img-col">
            <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="small-img-col">
            <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="small-img-col">
            <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12">
        <h6>Home / Morning Safari</h6>
        <h3>Morning Safari</h3>
        <h2> <label> Total:</label><label class="total Price"></label> </h2>
        <div class="counter1">
          <Label class="Adults">Adults</Label>
          <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount(event, this)'>-</div>
          <input type='text' value='1' readonly>
          <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="counter2">
          <Label class="Children">Children</Label>
          <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount2(event, this)'>-</div>
          <input type='text' value='0' readonly>
          <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="padding-left: 0;padding-top: 5px;">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="private" checked="checked">
            <label for="private">Private</label>
            <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="shared">
            <label for="shared">Shared</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="atv" id="withatv" checked="checked">
            <label for="withatv">With ATV</label>
            <input type="radio" name="atv" id="withoutatv">
            <label for="withoutatv">Without ATV</label>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    function increaseCount(e, el) {
      var input = el.previousElementSibling;
      var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value++;
      input.value = value;
    }

    function decreaseCount(e, el) {
      var input = el.nextElementSibling;
      var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
      if (value > 1) {
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value--;
        input.value = value;
      }
    }

    function decreaseCount2(e, el) {
      var input = el.nextElementSibling;
      var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
      if (value > 0) {
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value--;
        input.value = value;
      }
    }

    var MainImg = document.getElementById('MainImg');
    var smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName('small-img');

    smallimg[0].onclick = function() {
      MainImg.src = smallimg[0].src;
    }
    smallimg[1].onclick = function() {
      MainImg.src = smallimg[1].src;
    }
    smallimg[2].onclick = function() {
      MainImg.src = smallimg[2].src;
    }
    smallimg[3].onclick = function() {
      MainImg.src = smallimg[3].src;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Hi, I want multiple radio checkboxes. In one line it should be private or shared and in the second line it should be with ATV or Without ATV so people on my web can select shared and with ATV or many variables. so basically two selections are needed and 4four checkboxes are divided into two groups.

edited
i did what you said in comment it looks like this and its not same as private and shared

Answer (score 1):

[image: this is how it looks private and shared are up and down not in one line]The name tags on your ATV checkboxes should be changed from "occupancy" to something else like "atv". You could also wrap each group of inputs in separate divs if you want them to appear in separate rows. Finally you should also make your ids unique and update you label for tags so:

```
  <div class="container style1" style="padding-left: 0;padding-top: 5px;">
    <div class="">
              <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="private" checked="checked">
              <label for="private">Private</label>
              <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="shared">
              <label for="shared">Shared</label>
    </div>
    <div>
              <input type="radio" name="atv" id="withatv" checked="checked">
              <label for="withatv">With ATV</label>
              <input type="radio" name="atv" id="withoutatv">
              <label for="withoutatv">Without ATV</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I added a style1 class to your container but maybe you might want to add that style directly to .container. Anyway add these styles:

```
.style1{
flex-direction:column;
}
label[for="private"], label[for="shared"] { {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my post you can see the problem still appears to be same.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect your updated post